# Appending 3 images at once in HTML via HTTP GET request using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, get

I'm trying to send an Ajax request for each image that needs to be added in my HTML.
The way it works is that URL: "http://198.245.55.77/mars/camera.php has 10 images that we can get from by specifying the index of one of the images (index from 0 to 9). By uniting all images, we have a 360 degrees view of a landscape, so each image has a 36 degrees POV.

I'm only looking to get a 108 degrees POV on my page, so that would be looking for 3 consecutive images

Here's how my code looks like so far (I'm also a beginner at Jquery and Ajax, please bear with me)

```
"use strict";
$(function () {
    const MIN = 0;
    const MAX = 9;
    let numeroImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1; // Pige entre 1 et 8 inclusif au hasard
    console.log(numeroImage);
    
    requeteImage(numeroImage);

    $("input[type=button]:eq(0)").on("click", () => {
        if (numeroImage - 1 >= MIN) { numeroImage -= 1; }
        else { numeroImage = MAX };

        requeteImage(numeroImage)
    });

    $("input[type=button]:eq(1)").on("click", () => {
        if (numeroImage + 1 <= MAX) { numeroImage += 1 }
        else { numeroImage = MIN };

        requeteImage(numeroImage)
    });


    function requeteImage(numeroImage) {

        $(".images").html(""); // Supprimer les images précédentes

        for(let i = -1; i < 2; ++i) {

            $.get("http://198.245.55.77/mars/camera.php", { image: numeroImage + i })
            .done((data) => {
                $(".images").append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '">');
            })
            .fail((erreur) => {
                console.log(erreur);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I start by getting a random index from 1 to 8 to and execute function requeteImage to display 3 images the first time when the page completely loads.

The problem starts right there, and I think that's because the resquests are asynch, so it's not guarenteed they are executed in the right order. So, the images aren't really in order

Is there a way to fix it without using promises?

I tried to make three separate requests instead of doing a for loop and I tried to place them in if statements and execute them once the previous request is done, but it doesnt seem like it's working.

Thank you !

Comment: Instead of using `$(".images").append` why don't you put the images in the correct location since you know what their indexes are?

Comment: So, instead of `$(".images").html("")` , do `$(".images >img").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,...` with a "loading..." style image or spinner.  Then `.done((data) => $(".images>img").eq(i).attr("src", ....`  (OTTOMH might need to capture `i`)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by just adding async: false to my ajax request. However, I was wondering if it can be used or if it is discouraged to do sync ajax requests ?